# firebird no data

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework-5, firebird

I'm using a legacy Firebird-database in my Visual Studio 2012-project. I installed the NETProvider and DDEXProvider. I want to use Entity Framework, but I am unable to see the tablenames, etc. I've tried to connect to the local database (database.fdb) and when I test the connection it succeeds. However, I get all the categories (tables, views, procedures, system tables, etc.), but when I try to open an item the items are not displayed.
I've installed Flamerobin and the database opens as expected.
As you can see in the image, I use the standard login SYSDBA - masterkey.

Hopefully you can solve this problem.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: From your description it looks like you're in Server Explorer. Not in wizard to generate EDMX.

Comment: That's true. In both cases, creating the connection in EF5 or in Server Explorer, I get the same result. The connection test succeeds, but no schema with tables, views, etc. is returned. As already mentioned in my question: I can see the data when I use FlameRobin.

Comment: What's in Output Window from EDMX wizard?

Comment: HI My problem has changed. Tried to install again in a Virtual Machine. Windows 8 32-bit, Visual Studio 2012 Enterprise, Firebird 2.5.2 (32-bit) and NETProvider and DDEXProvider. Works correctly. Now I followed the same steps on a Windows 8 64-bit configuration. Firebird-datasource is available, but from the first character-input VS2012 encounters an expected error and shuts down. I guess the problem is 64-bit related, but I don't have a clue what I need to do to solve it. Hopefully you know the solution. Many thanks in advance.